# How can I remotely execute commands on a Windows Server from a Linux box?

Tags: linux, windows

I know that using WinRS or PsExec can do it from a Windows box, but I really need to do it from a linux box.

And Cygwin/OpenSSHd is not an option for license issues.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The RSHD suggested in the answers of this question, is insecure... Security is also an issue that we need to consider.

Comment: What are the license issues that preclude the use of cygwin/openssh ? Lots of other solutions may be invalid for the same reason.

Comment: It is company policy issue, GPLv3 is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

- I usually push for Cygwin + `sshd` because it integrates well.
- You could also consider a simple home-made command listener on specific port (telnet-alike or more specific) wrapped by `stunnel` for security.
- Another approach is CGI-script on Windows web-server.

  This approach is generic enough and can be run over HTTPS for security, but I would only suggest it for well-established interfaces (not for quick immediate stuff), when you are ready to run web-server for it.

---

**UPDATE regarding CGI**

I guess you can [start here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/cgi) to run CGI server on Windows.

Calling remote command over CGI from Linux can be done by `curl`.

One [googled introduction](http://www.purplepixie.org/cgi/howto.php) is complete enough and has sample C program to start with. To make the CGI approach clear, you may avoid web-server for testing by setting proper environment variables locally and running CGI program [directly from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2224748).

Comment: Do you have an example about the CGI script you mentioned?

Comment: @ciphor, I've added links with samples. All you need is to read environment variable from your CGI script to get input. The topic goes pretty far: security, web-server configuration, sample programs to do this and that, etc. I hope it can get you started.