# Running PowerSell Commands Remotely From A Linux Machine To Exchange Server

Tags: ssh, powershell, exchange-2010, python

Our client has a windows server 2008 with exchange 2010. I have to connect from linux machine to exchange server and search inside mail boxes via powershell.

I have searched here and found some solutions, but linkes o solution doesn't work for my issue:

[Connecting to Exchange PowerShell from a Linux machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/270580/connecting-to-exchange-powershell-from-a-linux-machine) 
[How can I remotely execute commands on a Windows Server from a Linux box? [duplicate] 1](https://serverfault.com/questions/485452/how-can-i-remotely-execute-commands-on-a-windows-server-from-a-linux-box)

There is many python libraries for this but I couldnt connect to exchange server with no one of them (paramiko, exchangelib, pyexchange with ip address, username, password)

Is there any setting for exchange server for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links you found are a little dated in light of events last year when MS started providing Powershell for Linux.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/powershell-is-open-sourced-and-is-available-on-linux/

> I am extremely excited to share that PowerShell is open sourced and available on Linux.

You can install Powershell on the Linux system and then use the `*-PSSession` cmdLets on the Linux system to get to the Windows system.
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

```
New-PSSession
Disconnect-PSSession
Connect-PSSession
Receive-PSSession
Get-PSSession
Remove-PSSession
Enter-PSSession
Exit-PSSession
Export-PSSession
Import-PSSession
```

Comment: Up to now - powershell 7.3, Connect-PSSession is not available on Linux platform, unfortunately.